# Efficient document format to store "Votes" in Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I'm trying to store "Votes" in MongoDB and I am stuck on how to proceed in an efficient way.
Basically , I have a question with several options like A B C D ...(6 total).
I am giving voters the option to choose an option and want to save the "Vote" with fields like:
MongoDate, option, voter name, and maybe couple more fields.

I am planning to have unlimited "Votes" in the thousands and even in millions on a given question.

In terms of retrieving the data : I would like to be able to query it mainly by Date  and present in charts, like a stock price with hourly, daily, monthly... intervals
In other words it is like time series.
I am not sure on the "format" of the document in MongoDB;

Answer (score 1):

One reasonable way to do it would be to have a votes collection, where each document looks like:

`{
    v: 'a', //voted for the first option

    d: Date(), //the date

    n: 'Bob',

    ...

 }`

Then, index on the date field.  Be careful not to shard on the date field alone, though, if you have to end up sharding this.  I listed the field names as single characters because the name of every field is stored in mongoDB, so for better space efficiency, you should use shorter names.  If you aren't concerned about space, a longer, more informative name is probably fine.

Comment: I am new to MongoDB , so let see if I see this the same way you do..   If i have 20 000 questions and lets say 100 000 voters that can vote on any question ...I will have "only" one collection for voting data and each document in that collection will be a "single" vote...does that mean I can load up the "votes" collection with practically millions of "single vote" documents...and votes for different questions...and index all that data b date and question reference ....and still keep good performance and speed ....

Comment: If you index on the date field, mongodb will keep a btree of dates in memory.  This is a matter of a few bytes, and a memory location.  Probably roughly 16 bytes in all per object.  If you have 100000 voters, realistically, how many questions will have many votes?  What really matters here is how many votes you have.  If every voter votes 100 times, there are ten million votes.  That is 160 million bytes, or around 1.2 gigs of memory.  If you have 2 gigs of memory, you can keep the entire index in memory and it will stay fast, since it will be Btree lookup.