# Order Posts by Most Votes (Overall, Last Month, etc.) with Laravel MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, php-mongodb

I am trying to understand more advanced functions of mongodb and laravel but having trouble with this. Currently I have my schema setup with a `users`, `posts`, and `posts_votes` collections. The `posts_votes` has a `user_id`, `post_id` and `timestamp` field.

In a relational DB, I would just left join the `posts_votes` collection, count, and order by that count. Exclude dates when need be and all that.

MongoDB I am having difficulty b/c there's no left join equivalent. So I'd like to learn how to accomplish my goal in a more document-y way.

On my `Post` model in Laravel, I reference this way. So looking at an individual post, I can get the vote count, see if current user voted for a specific post, etc.

```
public function votes()
{
  return $this->hasMany(PostVote::class, 'post_id');
}
```

And my current working query looks like this:

```
$posts = Post::forCategoryType($type)
    ->with('votes', 'author', 'businessType')
    ->where('approved', true)
    ->paginate(25);
```

The `forCategoryType` method is just extended scope I added. Here it is on the `Post` model/document class.

```
public function scopeForCategoryType($builder, $catType)
{
  if ($catType->exists) {
    return $builder->where('cat_id', $catType->id);
  }
  return $builder;
}
```

So when I look at [posts like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312419/mongodb-schema-design-voting-on-posts), it's close to what I want to accomplish, but I am not applying it properly. For instance, I changed my main query to look like this:

```
$posts = Post::forBusinessType($type)
    ->with('votes', 'author', 'businessType')
    ->where('approved', true)
    ->sortByVotes()
    ->paginate(25);
```

And created this new method on the `Post` model:

```
public function scopeSortByVotes($builder, $dir = 'desc')
{
  return $builder->raw(function($collection) {
   return $collection->aggregate([
    ['$group' => [
        '_id' => ['post_id' => 'votes.$post_id', 'user_id' => 'votes.$user_id']
      ], 
      'vote_count' => ['$sum' => 1]
    ],
    ['$sort' => ['vote_count' => -1]]

  ]);

});
}
```

This returns the error `exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`

Not sure how to fix that (still looking), so then I tried:

```
return $collection->aggregate([
        ['$unwind' => '$votes'],
        ['$group' => [
            '_id' => ['post_id' => ['$votes.post_id', 'user_id' => '$votes.user_id']],
            'count' => ['$sum' => 1]
          ]
        ]
      ]);
```

returns an empty `ArrayIterator`, so then I tried:

```
public function scopeSortByVotes($builder, $dir = 'desc')
  {
    return $builder->raw(function($collection) {
       return $collection->aggregate([
    '$lookup'    => [
      'from' => 'community_posts_votes',
      'localField' => 'post_id',
      'foreignField' => '_id',
      'as' => 'vote_count'            
    ]
  ]);

    });
  }
```

But on this setup, I just get the list of posts unsorted. On version 3.2.8.

The default loads everything by most recent. But ultimately I want to be able to pull these posts based on how many votes they got lifetime, but also query based on which posts got the most votes in the last week, month, etc.

That example I shared has the grand total linked in the `Post` model and an array of all the user ids that voted on it. With the way I have things setup using a separate collection holding the `user_id`, `post_id` and timestamps of when the vote happened, can I still accomplish the same goal?

Note: using this [laravel mongodb library](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).

Comment: I might be missing something here, but can't you replace ->sortByVotes() with ->orderBy('votes', 'DESC') ?

Comment: `votes` is a link to another table that has user_id, post_id, and timestamps. Essentially I need to group everything together by post_id and then sort by that result

Comment: You have a simple syntax error in aggregate where you close the $group subdocument too early.  So vote_count is not inside $group and that's why you get exception about the pipeline syntax.  It may be easier for people to help you if you use native MongoDB syntax to show documents and aggregation pipeline being used.